# grails data integrity violation exception and cause?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

The definition of Map is

```
class Map {

    MapCoordinate center
    Integer zoom
    List path

    static hasMany = [path: MapCoordinate]

    static hasOne = [center: MapCoordinate]

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

The definition of MapCoordinate is

```
class MapCoordinate {

    BigDecimal latitude
    BigDecimal longitude


    static belongsTo = [map: Map]

    static mapping = {

        latitude scale: 9
        longitude scale: 9

    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

This simple script fails with the following exception

```
Map map = new Map()

def cent = new MapCoordinate(latitude: 0.123, longitude: 0.2424)

map.center = cent

map.zoom = 5

map.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

Exception

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [MapCoordinate]; SQL [insert into map_coordinate (version, latitude, longitude, map_id, path_idx) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [MapCoordinate]
```

Can someone please explain to me what is the cause of this error? I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: I think that the problem is that you need a `Map` to save a `MapCoordinate` but since you need a `MapCoordinate` to save a `Map`, you are into a circular reference.

Comment: @rvargas can you suggest a solution? What i am trying to do is to create a map with a center, zoom and a list of paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the `MapCoordinate` has got only one `belongsTo` definition. On the other hand, you have got `hasOne` and `hasMany` within the `Map`. I suggest you change the structure of your domain classes to the following (including Randall's suggestion). With the `mappedBy` you make sure grails is able to identify the two relations correctly.

```
class Map {
    Integer zoom
    SortedSet path
    static hasMany = [path: MapCoordinate]
    MapCoordinate center

    static mappedBy = [path: "mapPath", center: "mapCenter"]

    static constraints = {
        center nullable: true
    }
}

class MapCoordinate implements Comparable {
    BigDecimal latitude
    BigDecimal longitude

    static belongsTo = [mapPath: Map, mapCenter: Map]

    static mapping = {
        latitude scale: 9
        longitude scale: 9
    }
    static constraints = {
        mapPath nullable: true
        mapCenter nullable: true
    }

    int compareTo(other) {
        if (id) {
            id.compareTo(other.id)
        }
        else {
            return -1
        }
    }

}
```

By adding the `SortedSet` you should be able to preserve the ordering of the `MapCoordinate` entries. However, the `MapCoordinate` class then has to implement the `Comparable` interface. Eventually, try to change the code as follows:

```
Map map = new Map()
def cent = new MapCoordinate(latitude: 0.123, longitude: 0.2424)
map.center = cent
map.zoom = 5
map.addToPath(new MapCoordinate(latitude: 0.33, longitude: 0.33))
map.addToPath(new MapCoordinate(latitude: 0.34, longitude: 0.34))
map.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

Comment: thanks! gabriel. How do you add path as well in addition to center in above code?

Comment: Either you add it to the constructor (`new MapCoordinate(mapCenter: map, mapPath: map, latitude: 0.123, longitude: 0.2424)`) or you can try by adding this line after the definition of `cent`: `map.addToPath(cent)`

Comment: gabriel, why is this not possible? map.center = new MapCoordinate(latitude: 0.123, longitude: 0.2424). in the example above, you are adding the same coordinate to path as well as center. they should be different. i tried to add a different coordinate to path and got the error. org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead

Comment: in this case, does mappedBy help distinguish which mapcoordinate is a center coordinate and which coordinate belongs to a path?

Comment: To your last comment: yes. I would add the center as propsed in my answer. Any other `MapCoordinate` which should be part of the path I would create with `new MapCoordinate(latitude: 1.33, longitude: 1.3245)` and then add the created instance with `map.addToPath(nameOfTheNewPathCoordinate)`. Imho this should work.

Comment: ok i added the map.addToPath(nameofnewcoordinate) but i get the error org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead

Comment: the full script code is as follows: 
Map map = new Map()
def cent = new Coordinate(mapCenter: map, latitude: 0.123, longitude: 0.2424)
map.zoom = 5

map.addToPath(new Coordinate(latitude: 0.33, longitude: 0.232))

map.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)

Comment: I have implemented the two domain classes as you have suggested above but still no luck. : (

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer. Note that I changed the definition of `Map` a little bit  and I implemented `compareTo` in `MapCoordinate` just for testing. Eventually, I changed the code with the test values a bit. For me that configuration worked.

Comment: i have restructured my domains in another way but i accepted your answer because of your effort. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused because `List path` is null and therefore entity cannot be saved. Please try to see how table Map does look in dataase and you will see that it has column `path` which is not nullable.

If you add entries to gorm's `hasMany` or `hasOne` then you don't need to explicitly create properties for  them. If you remove `center` and `path` then it should start working:

```
MapCoordinate center //remove this
Integer zoom
List path //remove this
```

Comment: commenting out the center and path properties fixes the error but the reason i have path type set to List is that i want to maintain order. I think not specifying the type will default to Set which in my case violates the requirement. can you offer a solution without changing the underlying datatypes? Thanks!